# Does positive thinking have any effect?

Tags: psychology, cognitive-science

I found [this](http://www.businessinsider.com/how-the-law-of-attraction-will-improve-your-life-2012-7?op=1) while reading about the 'Law of Attraction'

> Whether or not you believe in the power of the universe, there is scientific research that proves the effects of positive thinking.

Is this true? Is there any scientific research that proves the effects of positive thinking.

Comment: There's no claim here. What effects?

Comment: @Oddthinking Positive effects? :)

Comment: Related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/26/can-positive-thinking-provide-an-improved-outcome-for-an-illness?rq=1

Comment: i do have an answer for you, but it all depends upon beliefs.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is no claim here. It is just asking for any research about positive thinking. There's no actual claim to confirm or refute.

Answer (score 8):

Positive thinking does have effects, but they're not necessarily positive, according to Professor Richard Wiseman.
http://www.guardian.co.uk/science/2012/jun/30/self-help-positive-thinking

> In one study led by Lien Pham at the University of California, students were asked to spend a few moments each day visualising themselves getting a high grade in an upcoming exam. Even though the daydreaming exercise only lasted a few minutes, it caused the students to study less and obtain lower marks. In another experiment led by Gabriele Oettingen from New York University, graduates were asked to note down how often they fantasised about getting their dream job after leaving college. The students who reported that they frequently fantasised about such success received fewer job offers and ended up with significantly smaller salaries.

Wiseman recommends positive actions, like forcing yourself to smile.

> HAPPINESS: Smile
>   This is the granddaddy of them all. As Laird's study demonstrated, smile and you will feel happier. To get the most out of this exercise, make the smile as wide as possible, extend your eyebrow muscles slightly upward, and hold the resulting expression for about 20 seconds.

A previous [question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15103/is-the-gender-gap-in-male-dominated-areas-so-easy-to-overcome) here pointed to a study on values affirmation, where having physics students write about their most important values raised the exam scores of female students, but seemed to lower the scores of male students.

Comment: But I think there is only an equal probability for each happening sad or happy, successful or failed, but when you dreaming a happy end after gaining it by chance ( when your attempts can result winning or failing in an equal probability ) you think to your positive dreams and hopes before the matter and find it useful to gain your share by chance or your attempts so you refer it to "positive thinking" but no body likes to think to some who dreamed positive and gained nothing! ;))

Comment: I would say there is a large difference between people forcing themselves to appear positive (by smiling and forcing themselves to think positively) and those people who are naturally positive not through choice

Comment: Offtopic: R. Wiseman is quite well considered in skeptics’ world, but I think we should be careful about this “scientist”. One example of things that bother me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRAmvLV_EmY